# Javascript property assignment (vanilla)

Tags: javascript

for a little project I wanted to make a tiny library that detects browsers based on their engine:

```
var engine = {
opera: function(){
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
        version = ua.match(/opera[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/);
    if (version){
        return parseFloat(version[1]);
    }
},
webkit: function(){
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
        version = ua.match(/applewebkit\/([\d.]+)/);
    if (version && !engine.opera()){
        return parseFloat(version[1]);
    }
},
gecko: function(){
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
        version = ua.match(/rv\:([\w\.]+).\s(gecko)/);
    if (version && !engine.opera()){
        return parseFloat(version[1]);
    }
},
ie: function(){
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
        version = ua.match(/msie (\d+\.\d+)/);
    if (version && !engine.opera()){
        return parseFloat(version[1]);
    }
},
touch: function(){
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (ua.match(/android|ipod|iphone|ipad|iemobile|bb[\d]\d|blackberry|playbook|silk|touch|mobile/)){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

};

Call with: `engine.webkit()<534.3` to check if this is a webkit based browser older than what is used in Android 4 etc.

As you see I'm using property assignment to encapsulate the engine detection and not pollute the global namespace.

However - for each single engine, I'm creating the variable **ua**, which obviously isn't being reused and therefore not best practice.

Can someone show me a way on how to define **var ua** only once within the engine object?

Thank you

Comment: Just add `ua` to the `engine` object and then change all the `ua` references inside the functions to `this.ua`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the attribute and use with `this`:

```
ua: navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
opera: function {
    this.ua // The reusable
```

Comment: so your solution means, that when I call `engine.opera()` this again calls the `ua attribute` which stores the useragent. When I call` engine.webkit()` for example, the useragent is already cached within the `ua attribute`?

Comment: It is stored on instantiation and will not update unless you update it manually!

Answer (score 1):

Place it in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

```
var engine = (function() {
  var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  return {
    opera: function() { ... },
    // etc.
  };
})();
```

An IIFE works by creating a new function scope, which keeps variables out of the global scope, then immediately executes that function. `ua` effectively becomes a private variable. It's a local variable to the IIFE but can be referenced by any functions defined within the IIFE.

Comment: Thanks. Also a neat solution!